# Ion-select-option in ionic 4/5?

Tags: ionic4

I wish to bind the following JSON into ion-select. Can any one help me to finish this. Is the JSON looks fine?

```
{
        "1": "Lynko Pvt. Ltd. ",
        "4": "Letsclick Pvt. Ltd. ",
        "5": "Wirehead ",
        "6": "Codeyiizen Software & Services Pvt. Ltd. ",
        "7": "Mariao Barando ",
        "8": "Jorge Santacruz ",
        "9": "Matt Core ",
        "10": "Manny Singh ",
        "11": "Manoj Mishra ",
        "12": "Digi Interacts ",
        "13": "IHF Ltd. ",
        "14": "Hadiur Rahman ",
        "15": "The Football Link ",
        "16": "BSPL ",
        "17": "Votestalk ",
        "18": "Codeyiizen "
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind ion-select options as follows.Your JSON looks incorrect. I will give a reference code

```
<ion-item>
                    <ion-label data-target="#filter3">Travel Agencies</ion-label>

                    <ion-select id="filter3" multiple="true">
                        <ion-option id="filter3" *ngFor="let travels of filter_type.travels " value="{{travels.id}}">
                            {{travels.name}}</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-item>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i also said to my up line senor that JSON format is Incorrect.